# How to plot y=1/x as a single graph

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot

Is there an easy way to plot a function which tends to infinity in the positive and negative as a single plot, without the plot joining both ends of the positive and negative?

For example, plotting y=1/x using this code gives the resulting plot:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def f(x):
    return 1/x
fx_name = r'$f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$'

x=np.setdiff1d(np.linspace(-10,10,100),[0]) #to remove the zero
y=f(x)
plt.plot(x, y, label=fx_name)
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

[image: y=1/x]

But I would like this output, which I achieve by plotting two separate domains:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def f(x):
    return 1/x
fx_name = r'$f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$'

xfn=np.setdiff1d(np.linspace(-10,0,100),[0])
xfp=np.setdiff1d(np.linspace(0,10,100),[0])
yfn=f(xfn)
yfp=f(xfp)

yf = plt.plot(xfn, yfn, label=fx_name)
plt.plot(xfp, yfp, color=yf[0].get_color())
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

[image: y=1/x]

Is there are short-cut?
Many thanks.

### Solution

Include zero in the domain array, and suppress the divide by zero.  This forces one element of the returned co-domain array as "inf", and "inf" is not plotted.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def f(x):
    with np.errstate(divide='ignore', invalid='ignore'):
        return 1/x
fx_name = r'$f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$'

x=np.linspace(-10,10,101)
y=f(x)
plt.plot(x, y, label=fx_name)
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

[image: y=1/x]

I prefer this method since it avoids manual manipulation of the array, and can be easily reused for other functions which share the same domain (ex. y=1/(x+2)). Thank you all for contributions.

Comment: As a workaround you can make sure that you have zero in `x` rather than removing it (i.e. `x = np.linspace(-10,10,101)`). The plot will skip points that contain `inf` or `nan` resulting from 1/0.

Comment: `np.linspace(-10,10,100)` Does not go through `0` which is where you want your break. Change the code to  `np.linspace(-10,10,101)` so that the `0` is included in the text and should work ok ...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Actually you want to include `x = 0` because this results in `y = nan`, forming a gap in the plot.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def f(x):
    return 1/x
fx_name = r'$f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$'

# using 101 steps results in in array including the value 0
x=np.linspace(-10,10,101)
# f(0) = nan -> a nan value creates a gap
y=f(x)
plt.plot(x, y, label=fx_name)
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you.  This works too. But it does result in this error:
/opt/conda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:5: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in true_divide
  """

Is there a way to suppress this error in a Jupyter notebook?

Comment: np.seterr(divide='ignore', invalid='ignore') suppresses this error.
Thank you all.

Answer (score 7):

Not necessary easier as your workaround, but you could insert a 'nan' element at the index where the sign flips, for example:

```
idx = np.argmax(np.diff(np.sign(y)))+1

x = np.insert(x, idx, np.nan)
y = np.insert(y, idx, np.nan)
```

The 'nan' causes Matplotlib to interrupt the line.

Comment: Perfect, thank you.  That is very neat.

Answer (score 4):

based on [Rutger Kassies](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1755432/rutger-kassies) ideas:

```
n_points = 100
x=np.setdiff1d(np.linspace(-10,10,n_points),[0]) #to remove the zero

y=f(x)
y[n_points//2-1:n_points//2+1] = np.nan
```

use your original plot an set the points around 0 to `np.nan`. that way too many points get set to `None` but it's symmetric.

you could also setup your `linspace` to includ `0` such that `f(x) = np.nan`: `n_points = 101`. ([this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44041423/4954037) and 2 comments stated that right before i did... please credit there).