# matplotlib - Remove undefined number from plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot f(x) = 1/x using Python and matplotlib. Currently, my code is:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def f(x):
    return 1/x

t1 = np.arange(-4.0, 4.0, 1)
t2 = np.arange(-4.0, 4.0, 0.02)

figure = plt.figure(1)

ax = figure.add_subplot(111)
ax.tick_params(labeltop = True)
ax.set_ylim([-40,40])

plt.plot(t1, f(t1), 'bo', t2, f(t2), 'k')
```

The output is the following: 
[image: The output]

It's obviously incorrect, and I'm certain that the problem occurs due to the fact that Python can't calculate the function at point x = 0 (as 1/0 is undefined)

Is it possible to somehow exclude x = 0 from the function?

(There is a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44041021/how-to-plot-y-1-x-as-a-single-graph) that's pretty much the same as this one, but I was unable to solve the problem with the answers there.)

Thanks!

Comment: The solution is in the question itself using np.errstate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not incorrect. It simply connects each of the points, and when you have one point at + infinity and the other at - infinity at x = 0, you'll get this line connecting the two. The easiest way of plotting it without the line is by plotting two graphs: one for x < 0 and one for x > 0:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def f(x):
    return 1/x

t1a = np.arange(-4.0,     0, 1)
t1b = np.arange(   0,   4.0, 1)
t2a = np.arange(-4.0,     0, 0.02)
t2b = np.arange(   0,   4.0, 0.02)

figure = plt.figure(1)

ax = figure.add_subplot(111)
ax.tick_params(labeltop = True)
ax.set_ylim([-40,40])

plt.plot(t1a, f(t1a), 'bo', t2a, f(t2a), 'k')
plt.plot(t1b, f(t1b), 'bo', t2b, f(t2b), 'k')
plt.show()
```

resulting in:

[image]

Comment: Perfect, thank you!